# mysql Workbench: config setting to throttle size of files when imported via the Wizard?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've been using mysql workbench for several years on a Macbook Pro and have successfully imported both csv and json files with the Table Data Import Wizard. The wizard ate anything I fed it...csv files (24MB in size) with 40k lines or the identical data in a json file (83MB) with over 2.1 million lines. It always took a few minutes, but happily chugged away at the task. Imports of either format finished with no errors.

Unfortunately the Mac passed, so I've migrated to a new machine running Ubuntu 22.04. When trying to use the Table Data Import Wizard to ingest the identical files the Mac chewed up with ease, it imported the csv just fine but hung like a horse thief on the json file.

I have Google'd for any parameter my new setup may have that regulates intake of file size via the Table Data Import Wizard, but can find none. The mysql workbench forum did not have any threads that answered the question. I've confirmed both files were UTF-8 encoded.

On a positive note, when I broke the json file into smaller chunks, each digested just fine, but it isn't always convenient to do that from a workflow perspective.

A reasonable person would say, "Just import the CSV file and be done with it..." but progress is not made by reasonable people. While I can use dasel or another utility to convert between formats or just split the files into smaller chunks, I'd just like to know why the heck it worked on my Mac with no fuss but not on Ubuntu!

I've browsed some of he "max" settings but none seemed (to me) to obvisouly be related to the import Wizard. I would love any insights from more knowledgeable Workbench or MySQL users.

Many thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Try to adjust the value of max_allowed_packet to 256MB

Comment: Great suggestion.Adjusted max_allowed_packet to 256MB, restarted mysql, confirmed the value after restart and still choked on the file. Started looking at some other variables, but now am thinking I need to "let go" and just import the csv. LOL